# Fundamental GWT asynchronous call misunderstanding

Tags: gwt

I seem to be suffering from some fundamental misunderstanding of the way that GWT async calls work and/or how widgets are updated upon receipt of a callback.

I've created the two interfaces as well as the implementation and they seem to be communicating with one another.  I make this claim based on reasonable looking data observed while stepping through with the eclipse debugger: the `result` variable  in the onSuccess method below contains what I expect it to and the grid that I am attempting to populate ends up being filled with the data from `results` upon exit from the loop.  However when the `onSuccess` call returns, no grid is displayed in my GUI as per the `uhpScrollPanel.setWidget(uhpGrid)` call, and no exceptions of any sort are thrown.

I must be be overlooking something obvious, has anyone got any ideas about where to look?

```
    final ScrollPanel uhpScrollPanel = new ScrollPanel();
    uhpVert.add(uhpScrollPanel);
    uhpScrollPanel.setSize("100%", "100%");


    //build and populate grid
    UpdateHistoryServiceAsync uhpService = UpdateHistoryService.Util.getInstance();

    uhpService.getUpdateHistory(new AsyncCallback<List<UpdateHistoryEntryBean>>() {

        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            System.out.println("OnFailure");
            caught.printStackTrace();

            final Label uhpErrorLabel = new Label("Server Unable to Grab History...");
            uhpScrollPanel.setWidget(uhpErrorLabel);
            uhpErrorLabel.setSize("100%", "100%");

        }

        public void onSuccess(List<UpdateHistoryEntryBean> result) {
            int length = result.size();

            final Grid uhpGrid = new Grid();
            uhpScrollPanel.setWidget(uhpGrid);
            uhpGrid.setBorderWidth(1);
            uhpGrid.setSize("100%", "100%");
            uhpGrid.resize(length, 3);

            int i = 0;
            for (UpdateHistoryEntryBean entry : result) {
                uhpGrid.setText(i, 0, String.valueOf(entry.getSourceId()));
                uhpGrid.setText(i, 1, entry.getTitle());
                uhpGrid.setText(i, 2, entry.getBody());
                i++;
            }
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it turns out that the quick fix is to add the grid to a VerticalPanel rather than a ScrollPanel.  The question now becomes - why should that matter, and how do we get around this dilemma?

Comment: I think you need to post that as a seperate question, as it no longer has anything to do with your question title

Answer (score 0):

Your `onSuccess()` method is not defined correctly, as a parameter it receives an `Object`, and you must downcast it afterwards.

Meaning, the signature should be:

```
public void onSuccess(Object result)
```

After that, you can explicitly downcast the object you know you got back like so:

```
List<UpdateHistoryEntryBean> resultList = (List<UpdateHistoryEntryBean>) result;
```

Comment: Yuval, are you certain?  I'm using GWT 1.5 and Java 1.5 - full support for generics.  That method sig was generated via tool support (GWTDesigner to be specific...).  In any event the expected data is turning up in my result variable so I think 
that is not the issue.  Thanks for trying though!

Comment: Not the answer in this case but still a useful sanity check for anyone using GWT 1.4 but mistakenly compiling with 1.5 rules via some tool.